# How to simulate keyboard event in fmx delphi for utf8 language like Persian?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, keyboard-events

I want to find a function lick `keybd_event()` to send key to focused controllers 
but I couldn't find a guide for using that for UTF8 languages like Arabic, Persian, ...
should I use other ways or can you help me to use this method to UTF8 languages

Comment: You have to hive us more information about what you need to achieve. Is the component in question an edit box or something else? What is the desired effect you are looking for? I have dealt with Farsi/Persian text in Delphi/C++ Builder a lot. whiout knowing what you want to get at the end, it would be hard to answer your question.

Comment: `keybd_event()` is deprecated, use `SendInput()` instead. It supports sending Unicode characters.

Comment: dose `SendInput()` support utf8 languages? and can you please give me a link or sample code for using that

Comment: I tried to use but couldn't find uses class to add